# ms-access 2003 combo box population

Tags: sql, ms-access-2003

I have an entry form with a sub.  I have three combo boxes that work together.  combo 1 sets up with vba and an after event combo 2 and on into three.  They work fine independently of the main form, but when I sue the form as a sub the cascade stops working.

Forms

```
Main Form Name "1A-Event Entry"
SubForm Name "1B-Event sub"
```

ComboBox 1 (After Update)

```
Private Sub Category_AfterUpdate()
Me.Type = Null
Me.Type.Requery
Me.Type = Me.Type.ItemData(0)
End Sub
```

ComboBox 2 (SQL)

```
SELECT Type.ID, Type.Type, Type.Category
FROM Type
WHERE (((Type.Category)=[Forms]![1B-Event sub]![Category]))
ORDER BY Type.Type;
```

CombBox2 (After Update)

```
Private Sub Type_AfterUpdate()
Me.Detail1 = Null
Me.Detail1.Requery
Me.Detail1 = Me.Detail1.ItemData(0)
End Sub
```

ComboBox3 (SQL)

```
SELECT Detail.ID, Detail.Detail, Detail.Type
FROM Detail
WHERE (((Detail.Type)=[Forms]![1B-Event sub]![Type]))
ORDER BY Detail.Detail;
```

I am sure is has something to do with the Form/ Subform scripting in the SQL, but it escapes me.

Comment: Is [1B-Event sub] the name of a main form or a subform?

Comment: Remou, sorry that would help... I have modified the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a subform, you need a different reference:

```
WHERE Type.Category=[Forms]![1A-Event Entry]![Subform Control Name Here].Form![Category]
```

When a form is run as a subform of another form, you must refer to the subform control.

Comment: So Remou, the main takeaway would be for any combo reference the form name needs to be the primary form and not the sub form?

Comment: I did not quite catch that. If you refer to the main form, you can just say `Forms!Formname.Control`, if you refer to a subform, you must use additional properties, so: `Forms!Formname.Control^^.Form.Control` where `control^^` is a subform control.